# Constructor inheritance

Tags: java

```
public A {

  public A(String arg0) {
  ...
  }

  public A(String arg0, String arg1) {
  ...
  }

}

public B extends A {

}
```

I would like B to automatically have the constructors inherited from A without having to implement them explicitly like:

```
public B(String arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}
public B(String arg0, String arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Constructors are not inherited. Only the default one is automatically called on super classes, but still not "inherited".

The compiler will automatically add a call to the default constructor "super()" in every constructor, unless a constructor is explicitly called, and provided the superclass has a default constructor.

Moreover, if a classe doesn't explicitly define a constructor, the compiler will provide a default empty one, which as stated before calls the super() default constructor.

That's why it "looks like" the default constructor is "inherited", but it's just a compiler trick.

Comment: If the superclass doesn't have a default constructor, the compiler will give error cause it can't insert the "super()" call, and require an explicit call to one of the non-default constructors. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java Language Specification, section 8.8: Constructor declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8):

> Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding.

Answer (score 2):

**you can't**.As the Constructors can not be inherited in child classes.If we dont write any constructor in a class,a default one is provided.By using super keyword,we can call parent class constructor but with one condition i.e. it shud be the first statement in child constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Constructors aren't inherited between classes, and every subclass constructor has to call a superclass constructor as its first operation (explicitly or implicitly).