# What's wrong with Add() constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to add two numbers using multithreading but its showing the following error on compiling : 
" constructor Add in class Add cannot be applied to gives types;
class Input extends Add{
required: int,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Add implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    int a,b,c;
    Add(int a,int b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        t = new Thread(this,"add");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println("Exiting add thread.");
    }
}
class Input extends Add{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Add o = new Add(5,4);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String is : " + str);
        System.out.println("c: " + o.c);
    }
}
```

Comment: class Input extends Add{      //add written by mistake.

Comment: There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30923667/edit) link below the content of your question. You can select it and, uhm, **edit** the content of the question by yourself rather than posting a comment with a *fix*.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25629804/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1644317/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/15721764/1065197 and more and more...

Comment: I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/525548/1065197) is a better dup.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think that your duplicate is correct.  The solution here is to remove the inheritance, not to provide an explicit constructor that explicitly calls the superclass constructor.

Comment: @rgettman OP's question is why the compiler raises an error and those questions explain it. After understanding this, there are two solutions: 1) remove the `extends` as you explain in your post, or 2) let `Input` extend `Add` class and provide a proper constructor for the inheritance. Which one to use will depend on what OP exactly needs, but that we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only constructor available in `Add` takes two parameters, you must have a constructor in `Input` that explicitly calls it, but you don't.  The default, implicit constructor attempts to call the superclass constructor `Add()`, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

But you have your `Input` class extending `Add` for no reason.  Remove `extends Add` and it should compile.

```
class Input {
```